# Furnace with no filter is drawing air from the basement which has black mould. I am looking at renting this house?

Tags: basement, mold

The house I am looking at renting is old but nice. Problem furnace in the basement has had the outside air intake closed so only draws air from the basement. The filter has been taken away and parts of the pipes cut. There is mould in the basement ??help

Comment: Help? How? Don’t rent the house if it’s in dis-repair.

Comment: No air intake ? This can relate a safety hazard and would not be allowed in my state. Renting a place with a known possible health hazard make make you liable if someone gets sick.

Comment: Mold may or may not be a problem -- there are a zillion flavors of mold, from the nice to the utterly nasty.